# python os.chdir() cant be used multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I first use the os.chdir() it works then when I try using it again it does not and give me an error.
the following files have been created. ed and 123

```
import os 
os.mkdir('ed')
os.mkdir('123')
```

now i want to change between the two.

```
import os
os.chdir('ed')

os.chdir('123')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
os.chdir('123')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '123'
```

why wont it let me change between the two files ?

Comment: it isn't two files it's two directories. You can't navigate to `123/` when inside `ed/`; you'll need to up and then back in.

Answer (score 2):

Think of calling `os.chdir(some_path)` the same as doing `cd some_path` from the terminal. It considers the provided path to be relative unless being explicitly given an absolute path (starting with drive letter on Windows or `/` on Linux).

for `os.chdir('ed') ; os.chdir('123')` to work `123` dir must be a subdir of `ed`.
In your case it is not, so you will either need to:

1. provide absolute path
2. go back one level before calling `os.chdir('123')`:

   ```
   os.chdir('..')
   os.chdir('123')
   ```

   or even

   ```
   os.chdir('..{}123'.format(os.path.sep))
   ```

   Note the use of `os.path.sep` in order to avoid using OS specific path separator.

Comment: Is the use of `os.path.sep` really necessary here? I had the impression that `/` always works, even on Windows.

Comment: @tobias_k Use `/` and someone will complain, use `os.path.sep` and someone else would ;)  `/` indeed should work on Windows as well

Answer (score 2):

After creating ed and 123 folder, these two folders are at same level.

```
os.chdir('ed')
```

Above line will point you into ed folder.

```
os.chdir('../123')
```

You need to use .. to navigate to parent folder and then navigate to 123 folder.